# MSBUILD:error MSB1008: Only one project can be specified in Jenkins

Tags: asp.net, msbuild

I am facing an error while building project in Jenkins and Asp.net. My source code is on TFS. Below is the error message (Console output) for my build.

```
No history entries were found for the item and version combination specified.
Path To MSBuild.exe: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe
Executing the command cmd.exe /C C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe /t:Rebuild "/p:Configuration=Debug:Platform="Any CPU":CustomBuildPath="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Jenkins\\jobs\\PerformanceTest\\workspace\\PerformanceTest"" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\PerfomanceTest\workspace\PerformanceTest\PerformanceTest.sln" && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%% from C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\PerfomanceTest\workspace
[workspace] $ cmd.exe /C C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe /t:Rebuild '/p:Configuration=Debug:Platform="Any CPU":CustomBuildPath="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Jenkins\\jobs\\PerformanceTest\\workspace\\PerformanceTest"' "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\PerfomanceTest\workspace\PerformanceTest\PerformanceTest.sln" && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%%
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 4.0.30319.17929
[Microsoft .NET Framework, version 4.0.30319.18063]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

MSBUILD : error MSB1008: Only one project can be specified.
Switch: Files

For switch syntax, type "MSBuild /help"
Build step 'Build a Visual Studio project or solution using MSBuild' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Please resolve it.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to the double-quotes in Platform="Any CPU". Try to remove that and see if  it works.

Or try moving the SLN file path to the beginning of the command, before the switches.

Answer (score 0):

In vs2012 just try to create a Build definition "Test Build" using the default TFS template  "DefaultTemplate....xaml" (usually a copy of it)

It will fail with the usual self-explaining-error

```
MSBUILD : error MSB1008: Only one project can be specified.Switch: Activities`
```

Of course somewhere in the default TFS template some " are missing so msbuild will receive as parameter a non escaped directory containing spaces so will result in multiple projects(?!)

So NEVER use spaces in you TFS  Build Definition names, pretty sad and simple at the same time
R.Ballarino